# Concurrent access to static method that create internally a List

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

We came up with a strange bug, and after investigating the code seems that the only place where it could occur is inside a static method for a concurrency problem.

Could this code give any strange problem due to the creation of the List inside?

If this is the case, should I pass the list as a parameter to be thread safe (or make public and using directly the other static method)?

```
public static List<String> fooList(MyObject obj, List<String> listToCheck) {
    List<String> checkedWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String wordToCheck : listToCheck) {
        if (wordChecker(obj, wordToCheck)) {
            checkedWords.add(keyword);
        }
    }

    return checkedWords;
}

private static boolean wordChecker(MyObject obj, String word) {
    // doSomething
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You say you suspect a concurrency problem, but your code example gives us no information about how many threads might be calling those methods or, about what data those threads might share.  Concurrency problems _always_ revolve around shared data.  If there are no shared data, then there can be no problem; but could `obj` be shared? could `listToCheck` be shared?  Does `doSomething` touch any shared data?

Comment: Ok, I spotted the problem that was a different one! Anyway glad to know that I should be safe with this one. Thank you all, concurrency is always a nightmare! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted there are no threading issues with this code.

However, if your `doSomething` code does something with `static` data then there is a good chance bugs will arise through threading issues.